# How can I change password for domain user(windows Active Directory) using Python?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

How can I change the password for a domain user with Python? I have the ldap modules on board but have no solution. I managed to query the current settings via ldap, but how can modify it?

```
import ldap
import sys

host = 'ldap://10.172.0.79'

con = ldap.initialize(host)
BIND_DN = "administrator@biztalk.com"
BIND_PASS = "a-123456"
con.set_option( ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND, True )
con.set_option( ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 255 )

PASSWORD_ATTR = "unicodePwd"
username="bizadmin"
user_dn = "CN=%s,OU=User,OU=biztalk,DC=biz-talk,DC=com" % username
password = 'New12345'

# Set AD password
unicode_pass = unicode("\"" + password + "\"", "iso-8859-1")
password_value = unicode_pass.encode("utf-16-le")
add_pass = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, PASSWORD_ATTR, [password_value])]

# Replace password
try:
    con.modify_s(user_dn, add_pass)
    print "Active Directory password for", username, "was set successfully!"
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    sys.stderr.write('Error setting AD password for: ' + username + '\n')
    sys.stderr.write('Message: ' + str(e) + '\n')
    sys.exit(1)
```

error

pydev debugger: starting

Error setting AD password for: bizadmin

Message: {'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}

---

Python change domain(Microsoft Active Directory) user's password.

...requires certification services between python and domain?

Could you have any good ways to deal with it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working with Windows 2012 R2 AD:

First install latest ldap3 package:
sudo pip install ldap

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ldap3

SERVER='127.0.0.1'
BASEDN="DC=domain,DC=com"
USER="user_domain_login_name@domain.com"
CURREENTPWD="current_password"
NEWPWD="new_password"

SEARCHFILTER='(&(userPrincipalName='+USER+')(objectClass=person))'

USER_DN=""
USER_CN=""

ldap_server = ldap3.Server(SERVER, get_info=ldap3.ALL)
conn = ldap3.Connection(ldap_server, USER, CURREENTPWD, auto_bind=True)
conn.start_tls()
#print conn
conn.search(search_base = BASEDN,
         search_filter = SEARCHFILTER,
         search_scope = ldap3.SUBTREE,
         attributes = ['cn', 'givenName', 'userPrincipalName'],
         paged_size = 5)

for entry in conn.response:
    if entry.get("dn") and entry.get("attributes"):
        if entry.get("attributes").get("userPrincipalName"):
            if entry.get("attributes").get("userPrincipalName") == USER:
                USER_DN=entry.get("dn")
                USER_CN=entry.get("attributes").get("cn")

print "Found user:", USER_CN
print USER_DN
print ldap3.extend.microsoft.modifyPassword.ad_modify_password(conn, USER_DN, NEWPWD, CURREENTPWD,  controls=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is not my language, but changing the Active-Directory password via LDAP is something I do.

As far as your URL is concerned :

Your LDAP URL should be like  :

```
host = 'LDAP://10.172.0.79/dc=directory,dc=example,dc=com'
```

With 'LDAP' and not 'ldap' and the good directory path behind.

As far as the password is concerned :

**First** : As far as I understand you can change the AD pasword `unicode_pass` only if you server has a certificate and if you contact if via LDAPS (SSL).

**Second** : the password is given with double qote password test.2006 becomes "test.2006".

**Third** : the resutl must be coded in unicode.

---

Edited :

Once you have installed Certificate Server you just have to reboot your server to have AD waiting on port 636 (LDAPS). On Python side, here is what I found :

```
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
l = ldap.initialize("LDAPS://10.172.0.79:636")
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS,ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND)
l.set_option( ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND, True )
l.set_option( ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 255 )
l.simple_bind_s("admin@tester.com","password")
```

Comment: How can i set my server has a certificate and contact with via LDAPS(SSL)? I install certificate servers in my server,but i cann't contact with ldap. if you have step by step, could you share to me? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for you help. But it's not works. On Python side,no need certificate file......?

Comment: As usual in SSL you need to import the public key certificate of the certification authority.

Answer (score 0):

The password change code looks perfect.

you are not binding after initialize. bind is a must.

```
con.simple_bind_s(user, pass)
```

Also, for starters you can ignore certificate errors for bind by setting this option. Once you are able to update password, you can harden the certificate thingy if you want.

```
con.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
```